# Footnote in math mode

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

How can I insert a footnote into math mode? I tried this (with required packages)

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{ccaption}
```

And i.e if I try

```
\begin{eqnarray}
foo && foo \text{\footnote{something}}\\
foo && foo \mbox{\footnote{something else}}
\end{eqnarray}
```

the link to the footnote appears, but not in the footnote position and if I click it I'm redirected to the first page. If I am in text mode I don't have this problem.
How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 66):

You shouldn't be using `eqnarray`, first of all, but rather `align`.

```
\begin{align}
a &= b && \text{something\footnotemark} \\
c &= d && \text{other}
\end{align}
\footnotetext{text of the footnote}
```

While `\footnote` works in `equation`, it doesn't in other alignment environments.

Comment: your advice works with both (eqnarray and align) but from now on I'll use align

Comment: @Bruce_Warrior, exactly. This method works just fine in `align` and its derivatives (`align*`, `aligned`, etc) just fine.

Comment: But what if the math is at the bottom of one page and the `\footnotetext{text of the footnote}` is forced to a second page because of lack of space? Won't that lead to the strange result of showing the actual footnote on a different page than the footnote mark?

Comment: @L.F. Yes, that's a risk when using this. I recommend never footnoting math.

Answer (score 39):

According to Kopka and Daly, *A Guide to LaTeX*, p. 96--97, the `\footnote` command is not allowed in math mode, so you'll have to resort to using `\footnotemark` inside math environments and `\footnotetext{<Some text>}` in normal text mode.

Note that if, as in your example, more than one footnote is needed, you have to adjust the `footnote` counter by subtracting `n-1` (`n` being the number of footnotes in math mode) before the first `\footnotetext` and using `\stepcounter` before all other occurences of `\footnotetext`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{eqnarray}
foo && foo \footnotemark\\
foo && foo \footnotemark
\end{eqnarray}

\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{something}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{something else}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do that but the firts footnotemark redirect me to first page and the second footnote works fine redirect me to the localization of the second footnote. Do you know why this happen to me?

Answer (score 21):

If you want to put footnotes in `equation` environment, just use `\footnote` in math mode:

```
\begin{equation}
foo\footnote{bar}
\end{equation}
```

For `eqnarray` environment or some other complex environments, use:

```
\begin{eqnarray}
foo\footnotemark
\end{eqnarray}
\footnotetext{bar}
```

(Well, `eqnarray` is wicked, see [eqnarray vs align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align))

---

However, it is not a good manner to use footnotes in math equations. The default marks could be considered as exponents. If it is really necessary, it is better to redefine `\thefootnote` to get a different mark style. For example:

```
% symbol sequence: * \dagger \ddagger \S \P ...
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

or

```
% circled number: ①②③④⑤⑥⑦⑧⑨
\usepackage{pifont}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\ding{\numexpr171+\value{footnote}}}
```