# Numbering problem with footnotes in epigraph

Tags: numbering, footnotes, epigraphs

I am having some difficulty with the numbering of a couple of footnotes in an epigraph. Using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, both the footnotes are given the same number although the contents are correct. Using `\footnotemark[1]` doesn't help either. I am using the `epigraph` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.9\textwidth}
\renewcommand{\epigraphflush}{center}
\renewcommand{\sourceflush}{flushright}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushleft}
\setlength{\afterepigraphskip}{.2\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{epigraphs}
\qitem{Epigraph one blah blah blah?\footnotemark Blah blah\footnotemark blah}%  
{---\textsc{Author A}}
\qitem{Epigraph two blah blah}%
{---\textsc{Author B}}
\end{epigraphs}
\footnotetext{one}
\footnotetext{two}
\noindent Blah blah blah\footnote{three}. Blah blah Blah.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a problem with the `epigraphs` environment, but a general limitation of the `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` workaround. If you use this combo for multiple footnotes, you have to adjust the footnote counter by subtracting `n-1` (`n` being the number of footnotes) before the first `\footnotetext` and using `\stepcounter` before all other occurences of `\footnotetext`. Modify your example as follows:

```
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{one}
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{two}
```

(NOTE: I have given this hint [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode/21817#21817) before, but I don't consider your question a duplicate.)

Comment: Although this works, it seems to break hyperref. Do I just put up with that, or is that another question?

Comment: @RSoul: That's another question (one I'd like to know the answer myself).

Comment: I opted for Lockstep's solution with `\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`