# References inside floats as footnote bibliography

Tags: biblatex, floats, footnotes

I'm working on my thesis and I would like (for the sake of readability) the references to appear at the bottom of each page as footnotes, as well as at the end of the text, in the bibliography.

This is all solved dandy by using the `footnote-dw` style inside the `biblatex` package (`\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}`), however, my problem is that I have references inside floats (tables/figures)- for instance when using an image from another article/book- and these don't appear as footnotes, they are simply skipped!

How do I make them appear as footnotes, together with the other references?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behaviour is not directly related to `biblatex` (and not specific to the `biblatex-dw` styles) -- "normal" footnotes are simply gobbled inside floats, and one has to manually set `\footnotemark` *inside* plus `\footnotetext{Some text}` *outside* the float. To combine this workaround with `biblatex`' citation commands, I suggest to use `\footnotetext{\fullcite{<key>}.}` (note the closing period).

Note: Consectutive instances of the `\footnotemark`/`footnotetext` combo (without a normal `\footnote` in between) need additional manual intervention -- for details see [Numbering problem with footnotes in epigraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26766/numbering-problem-with-footnotes-in-epigraph).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=250pt% just for the example

\begin{document}

\section{First}

Some text \autocite{A01}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption[A figure]{A figure\footnotemark}
\end{figure}

\footnotetext{\fullcite{B02}.}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! That did the trick. Now off to edit all figures :-) !!

Comment: @Horea You may also thank me by accepting my answer and (as soon as you have 15 rep) upvoting it.

Comment: I have one more problem. If both references are the same in your example (A01 and B02), they get cited both times in the footnotes. Is there a way to make Biblatex index them once? Thank you

Comment: @Horea Try to replace the second `\fullcite` with `\cite`.

Comment: @lockstep I am trying to use your above code but I am getting 7 warnings.  Is the above code a MWE? What am I doing wrong? Thanks