# Footnote in align environment

Tags: footnotes, amsmath, align

It appears that one is *not* supposed to use `\footnote` in math mode as per this appropriately named question: [Footnote in math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode).  However, it appears that I can get it to work without having to resort to `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, as long as I use a `minipage`:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein}\footnote{Better check this.}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
```

which yields:

[image]

Ok, so that seems to be working.

But wait.. The text of the `\footnote` duplicated!!!  Hmmm, must be the measuring stage that align goes thru.  Ok, then that should be easy to fix: all we need to do is to check `\ifmeasuring@`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
    \ifmeasuring@
    \else
        \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother
```

Now using `\AlignFootnote{}` instead of `\footnote{}` we get the desired results:

[image]

Ok, but in this first use case (Einstein) I just happened to use the `\footnote` inside the `\text{}`.
Trying to use `\AlignFootnote{}` outside of the `\text{}` (Newton) really screws this up for some reason:

[image]

So in the Newton use case, it appears as if the content outside of the `\text{}` goes thru 4 non-measuring passes.

### Attempted Fix:

Well the obvious thing to try was to use `\text{\footnote{#1}}`, but that not only has no effect on the second use case, it also messes up the first use case: both footnotes show up 4 times.

### Questions:

- Main question: Is there a way to detect the repeated passes outside of `\text{}` so that I don't have `\footnotes` duplicated without resorting to `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext`?
- Why is the `minipage` required? Without it the `\footnotes` don't show up at all.  Is there some flushing type of macro required that would make them show up?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
    \ifmeasuring@
    \else
        \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein}\AlignFootnote{Better check this.} \\
    F &= mb   &&\text{Newton\AlignFootnote{This also seems wrong for some reason.}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Related Question: [Can I make footnote inside an equation?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/can-i-make-footnote-inside-an-equation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`amstext.sty` defines a `\iffirstchoice@` test just for this: it is true in the first branch of the inner `\mathchoice` called by `\text` and false in the remaining three.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \iffirstchoice@
      \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein}\AlignFootnote{Better check this.} \\ 
    F &= mb   &&\text{Newton\AlignFootnote{This also seems wrong for some reason.}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Actually the size of the footnote mark is not taken into consideration for the size of the equation, so a more correct answer would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    \chardef\@tempfn=\value{footnote}%
    \footnotemark
    \setcounter{footnote}{\@tempfn}%
  \else
    \iffirstchoice@
      \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

that prints only the footnotemark and restores the counter at its previous value.

**Limitation** If you say `\dfrac{\text{Newton\AlignFootnote{X}}}{2}` you won't get the footnote. But this shouldn't be a big deal.

If you want to use the `\footnote` command, this works

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\original@footnote\footnote
\newcommand{\align@footnote}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    \chardef\@tempfn=\value{footnote}%
    \footnotemark
    \setcounter{footnote}{\@tempfn}%
  \else
    \iffirstchoice@
      \original@footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\pretocmd{\start@align}{\let\footnote\align@footnote}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein\footnote{Better check this.}} \\
    F &= mb   &&\text{Newton\footnote{This also seems wrong for some reason.}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Note.** The above codes only work for when we're inside `minipage`. For *outer* footnotes the only way is to use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, with some adjustments not to make the counter advance too many times.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\original@footnotemark\footnotemark
\newcommand{\align@footnotemark}{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    \chardef\@tempfn=\value{footnote}%
    \original@footnotemark
    \setcounter{footnote}{\@tempfn}%
  \else
    \iffirstchoice@
      \original@footnotemark
    \fi
  \fi}
\pretocmd{\start@align}{\let\footnotemark\align@footnotemark}{}{}
\makeatother

\textheight=4cm % just to produce a smaller picture

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein\footnotemark} \\
    F &= mb   &&\text{Newton\footnotemark}
\end{align*}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\footnotetext{Better check this.} 
\addtocounter{footnote}{1}
\footnotetext{This also seems wrong for some reason.}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ahhh, so `\mathchoice` is where the 4 repetitions are coming from.

Comment: Shouldn't you also do the footnote mark (but not `\insert` the footnote text) on the measuring run and textstyle (2nd) branch of mathchoice if you want the measuring to be right? (and then reset the counter appropriately?)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `align` uses `\displaystyle`, so the second branch should not be necessary, if the `\text` is not in the numerator or denominator of a fraction or in a radical (which I believe would be *very* devious). I'll do some more tests.

Comment: @egreg -- this is certainly bravura code.  i do hope it doesn't result in a request to add `\footnote` capabilities to `amsmath`'s multi-line display facilities.  (the answer will almost certainly be "no".  we agree with kopka & daly.)

Comment: Is there a way to make this work with the original `footnote` command so that I can use my own macro's (that I use outside of `align` as well) in the align ervironment?

Comment: @SydKerckhove I expanded my answer. But avoid footnotes in math, so the problem doesn't show up to begin with.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you! I just want to overset footnotes over `=` signs to give a reference to the reason that this equality holds. This way there are no mixups with exponents.

Comment: @SydKerckhove That's what I feared. Don't! `;-)` A side comment is much better.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from, but the footnote is less intrusive. It allows you to find out why something is true if you really don't know. You're not supposed to not know.

Comment: I have another problem with this. The footnote doesn't work inside an align environment unless it's in a frame :s
The footnote number appears, but the footnote doesn't and there's a warning about this in the log.

Comment: @SydKerckhove What “frame”?

Comment: Unless It's in a frame created by a `\newmdtheoremenv{bal}[thm]{Algoritm}` command from the `mdframed` package.

Comment: @SydKerckhove This requires a new question. But probably you just have to push `\footnotetext` outside the environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22959/discussion-between-syd-kerckhove-and-egreg).

Answer (score 4):

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\fakeFN}[1]{\@makefnmark}
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
    \ifmeasuring@% I want to use \@makefnmark here, too,
                 % but \@thefnmark is undefined.
                 % The substitute "kerning" (see \else branch) is a work-around, but
                 % messes with align's spacing.
    \else%
        \footnote{#1}\sbox0{\@makefnmark}\kern-\wd0%
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\newdimen\myparboxwidth
\newcommand{\textfn}[1]{% I need to increment the fnmark counter here …
  {\LetLtxMacro\footnote\fakeFN\sbox0{#1}\global\myparboxwidth=\wd0}
  \parbox{\myparboxwidth}{#1}%
}

%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} % for the second output
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth} 
\begin{align*} 
E &= mc^3 &&\text{Einstein}\AlignFootnote{Better check this.} \\
F &= mb &&\textfn{Newton\AlignFootnote{This also seems wrong for some reason.}}
\end{align*}
\end{minipage}

\begin{align*}
E &= mc^2 &&\text{Einstein is happy now.} \\ 
F &= ma &&\text{Newton, too.}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Output with `lua-visual-debug` activated

[image]