# Compute remaining horizontal space in align environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align, lengths

I use `align*` often and sometimes it is preferable to add text to the right hand side of an equation instead of using `\intertext`, or `\shortintertext`, which tends to interrupt the math flow.  This is pretty straightforward using `\text{}`, *except* if the text is longer than the amount of space available. In this case I use a `\parbox` and tweak the width of it until it *fits*, as in the first set of equations:

[image]

However, I am wondering if there is a way to define the `\RemainingSpace` macro below as some `\dimexpr` expression so that it computes the amount of horizontal space that is available to the `\parbox`?

Or, is there a better way to do this? I realize a `tabularx` solution would work, but `align` is really preferable when it comes to equations.

---

### Minipage:

- The problem is much worse when working in a `minipage` was the width is reduced. An image of that is *not* included here but is on Page 2 of the output generated by the MWE below.

---

### Notes:

- I am not really worried about the issue of numbering equations, but that might be useful for others.
- Am assuming that the same solution would work with `alignat*`, but have added a test case for that just in case.

---

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\RemainingSpace}{9.0cm}%
\newcommand{\Note}[1]{\parbox[t]{\RemainingSpace}{#1}}%

\newcommand*{\RubbishText}{This was obvious once it was determined that the earlier versions $E = mc$ and $E = mc^3$ were not quite accurate.}%

\newcommand{\TestCases}{%
    First using \textbf{align*} with a \textbf{quad} for spacing:
    \begin{align*}
        E &= mc^2 \quad\Note{\RubbishText}\\
        F &= ma + \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 1.
    \end{align*}
    Or could use double ampersand for spacing (but less important than the above version):
    \begin{align*}
        E &= mc^2 &&\Note{\RubbishText}\\
        F &= ma + \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 1
    \end{align*}
    Or, using \textbf{alignat*}
    \begin{alignat*}{2}
        E &= mc^2 \quad\Note{\RubbishText}\\
        F &= ma + \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x - 1
    \end{alignat*}%
}%


\begin{document}\noindent
\TestCases

\clearpage\noindent
Same code as above but put in a \verb|\minipage{0.70\linewidth}|:
\bigskip

\hspace*{0.25\linewidth}%
\begin{minipage}{0.70\linewidth}
    \TestCases
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: `cos` --> `\cos` ;)

Comment: @SvendMortensen: Argghhh!!! I made a similar mistake with `\sin` before.... Thanks. Am fixing...

Comment: Glad to "help". (Not that it is any real help, actually.)

Comment: @SvendMortensen: I agree that that does help with getting a working solution to this, but it is not good to have sloppy questions either -- others might see this and think it is ok to use `cos`. Still thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Related Question: [How can I create a box which extends to the end of the line?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/386789/4301).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

takes a couple of runs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\RubbishText}{This was obvious once it was determind that the earlier versions $E = mc$ and $E = mc^3$ were not quite accurate.}%

\makeatletter
\newcount\zzz
\def\foo{%
\global\advance\zzz\@ne
\ifmeasuring@
\else
\expandafter\ifx\csname zz\romannumeral\zzz\endcsname\relax
\else
\edef\RemainingSpace{\the\dimexpr 30000000sp - 
         \csname zz\romannumeral\zzz\endcsname sp\relax}%
\typeout{\the\zzz: \RemainingSpace}%
\fi
\pdfsavepos
\edef\tmp{\write\@auxout{%
  \gdef\noexpand\noexpand\expandafter\noexpand
    \csname zz\romannumeral\zzz\endcsname{\noexpand\the\pdflastxpos}}}
\tmp
\fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\RemainingSpace}{9.0cm}%

\begin{document}\noindent


First using \verb|align*| with a \verb|\quad| for spacing:
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 \quad\foo\parbox[t]{\RemainingSpace}{\RubbishText}\\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1.
\end{align*}
Or could use \verb|&&| for spacing (but less important than the above version):
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 &&\foo\parbox[t]{\RemainingSpace}{\RubbishText}\\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1
\end{align*}
Or, using \verb|alignat*|
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    E &= mc^2 \quad\foo\parbox[t]{\RemainingSpace}{\RubbishText}\\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks good, but any reason why the text does not go to the right margin as it does in the `linegoal` solution?  I thought it was for the equation numbers but that does not appear to be the case.

Comment: `30000000sp` seems to be a hardcoded text width? This nice method will fail with `\documentclass[a5paper]{article}`, or give an unexpected result if the whole thing is in a `minipage` of say `0.5\linewidth`.

Comment: @user700902 sure I was just getting tired, you can calculate the value from `\textwidth` or simpler just stick a \pdfsavepos flush right in the page head on the first page and get the value from the @aux file

Comment: @PeterGrill that's because I was tired and just puled 30000000sp out of the air, see above comment^^

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Saving the right edge position won't work for the `minipage` example. So, how do you calculate what the `30000000sp` should be based on the `\linewidth`?  Have updated test case to check for behavior in a `minipage`.

Comment: well you could just do \hfill\pdfsavepos which would save the right extent (but could mess up centering unless done with care. I had a quick look at the linegoal package and that's basically doing same as this answer using pdfsavepos and then taking account of \linewidth and odd/evenside margin so presumably also doesn't work in positioned minipages? anyway no time this evening:-)

Answer (score 8):

The package [`linegoal`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/linegoal) and its `\linegoal` macro produce —after two compilations—the correct output. But they throws errors and warnings, probably due to how `amsmath`’s environments process their contents.

egreg saved me from going through answers and code and provided the `\ifmeasuring@` conditional from `amsmath`.

I have defined a `\Note` macro that hides the text from the measuring.
Sadly, this does not work for the `&&` version of `align*` as `amsmath` needs to know the width to align the columns correctly.

I have therefore provided a starred version of `\Note` that does the same as before, still producing warnings and errors.

Note that I have included the `\quad` in the un-starred version of `\Note`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{linegoal}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\RubbishText}{This was obvious once it was determind that the earlier versions $E = mc$ and $E = mc^3$ were not quite accurate.}%

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Note}{\@ifstar\s@Note\@Note}
  \newcommand*{\@Note}[1]{\ifmeasuring@\else\quad\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1}\fi}
  \newcommand*{\s@Note}[1]{\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}\noindent
First using \verb|align*| with a \verb|\quad| for spacing:
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 \Note{\RubbishText} \\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1.
\end{align*}
Or could use \verb|&&| for spacing (but less important than the above version):
\begin{align*}
    E &= mc^2 & \Note*{\RubbishText}\\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1
\end{align*}
Or, using \verb|alignat*|
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    E &= mc^2 \Note{\RubbishText}  \\
    F &= ma + \sin^2 x + cos^2 x - 1
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: That's a very good idea; you could try `\newcommand\RemainingSpace[1]{\ifmeasuring@\else\quad\parbox[t]{\linegoal}{#1}\fi}`. This doesn't work with `&&` in `align*`, but it does in `alignat*`. Don't forget `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I remember `\ifmeasuring@` from other answers. `:)` I have included a `\Note` macro in my answer that has a starred “dull” version for the `&&` variant of `align(at)*`.

Comment: If you say `&&\Note{...}` in `alignat*`, you get the same result as the warning producing version with `align*`.

Comment: Could someone explain what `\ifmeasuring@` does?  I can't find any documentation for it and looking at `amsmath.sty` doesn't help either.

Comment: @A.Ellett: In simple terms (as I am not an expert on the details) align does two pass processing: in the first pass it measures things so it knows how how wide they are and where to align then. Then in the second pass it does the typesetting now that it know how wide things are. In [Footnote in align enviroment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82782) not only does `\ifmeasuring@` arise, but so does `\iffirstchoice@`. But perhaps you should post a new question on that.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: This also doesn't work in a `minipage`. Have updated the test case.  Also good idea of using a `\Note` macro. Have incorporated that in the updated test case.

Comment: @PeterGrill The `minipage` is very weird. The horizontal space in front of the minipage (may it be your `\hspace` or a par indent) will be seen as a right padding of the `\Note` macro. On top of that there is even an `\if@minipage` and one could save `\linegoal` at the start of a `minipage` but somewhere along the way to the `\Note` macro those information are lost again. This will need more investigation …

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Wow, that is interesting. I only put the `hspace` there to make it obvious that the `minipage` was not working. I initially did not have the `\hspace` and David's solution _seemed_ to be working just fine in the `minipage`.  Only after looking carefully was it obvious that the reduced width was being ignored all together.  Am surprised that this issues has not already been solved as it seems like a natural thing to want to do.  I been struggling with this for a while and just assumed that there was a solution, but I hadn't come across it yet.