# How to split text within align

Tags: align

The text is too long and would like to split it in two: Any help please!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
\textit{K}^{k,r}_{j}&   : \text{The transportation and handling \\ of item $k$, type $r$ machines in period $j$}& 
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Using a `\parbox` should work.

Comment: Peter am new to latex, could you please revise it for me? Thanks

Comment: It would help if we have a complete example of what you have in mind: as is, your text has nothing to do with an align environment. Is it the description/ explanation of some mathematical notation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to cope with this is with a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tabular}{l@{}l}
$K^{k,r}_{j}$ : \mbox{} & The transportation and handling of \\
                        & item $k$, type $r$ machines in period $j$
\end{tabular}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\textit{K}` is not needed: a “K” in math mode is italic by default.

Answer (score 6):

As Peter Grill mentioned in a comment, a `\parbox` ("paragraph-containing box") provides a fine solution method. The `\parbox` macro takes three arguments: the first, which is optional (and hence gets placed in square brackets), specifies the alignment: `t`, `m` (default), and `b`; the second specifies the width, and the third the actual text that needs to be typeset.

In the example below, I've chosen 3.5" as the width of the parbox; obviously, you're free to choose a different width. (For a way to make LaTeX compute the maximum available width and make it available to the parbox, see the posting [Compute remaining horizontal space in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100495/5001). (Thanks to Peter Grill for suggesting this possibility.)

The `\raggedright` instruction in the MWE -- suggested by @daleif -- at the start of the second required argument instructs LaTeX to typeset the text in raggedright mode rather than fully-justified mode; this is useful for avoiding potential extreme stretching of the text. The horizontal line above the equation is there just to illustrate the width of the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of the text block
\begin{equation*}
K^{k,r}_{j} :\ 
\parbox[t]{3.75in}{\raggedright The transportation and handling of item~$k$, 
   type~$r$ machines in period~$j$}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: An essentially equivalent result can be achieved by typesetting the material in a two-column `array` environment, with the second column being of type `p` -- essentially a "parbox". Here's just the equation part of the required code (the preamble is the same as above):

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{@{} l p{3.75in} @{}}  % choose width of `p` column to suit your needs
K^{k,r}_{j} : &
\raggedright The transportation and handling of item~$k$, type~$r$ machines in period~$j$\\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding a `\raggedright` to the `\parbox` or one can easily end up with excessive stretch.

Comment: @daleif - Good idea! I'll add the instruction to the MWE.

Comment: @Mico: You could also incorporate the code from [Compute remaining horizontal space in align environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100495/compute-remaining-horizontal-space-in-align-environment) so that you don't have to guess at the width.

Comment: @PeterGrill - thanks for this suggestion; I'll mention it in a comment. For the equation at hand, it may be preferable to choose a fixed width based on the most desirable look of the material in the parbox.

Comment: @PeterGrill math that wide seldom look attractive