# Can I make footnote inside an equation?

Tags: equations, footnotes

Can I make a footnote to clarify an important point inside an equation?

Comment: any problem in trying it yourself or is it a general question about the sense?

Comment: There is no link to the footnote but there exists no footnote.

Comment: Related Question: [Footnote in align enviroment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/footnote-in-align-enviroment).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First: think carefully whether that is the right thing to do, then don't do it. Most symbols for footnote marks can have a mathematical meaning. I once spent several minutes wondering about the meaning of a mathematical expression before I deduced that one of the exponents had to be a footnote mark. My preferred methods of explaining parts of an equation are to explain it in words either before or after the equation, or within the equation as a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
In the following expression, $q$ is required to be an integer:
\[ 
    n = q\cdot k
\]
And here is another equation:
\[ 
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \qquad\text{($c$ is required to be an integer.)}
\]
\end{document}
```

If one really must have a footnote, you can just try the `\footnote` command. This can fail in some circumstances, in which case one can use the pair of commands `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, the latter outside the math environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Plain footnote works:
\[ 
    X^2 = Y\footnote{$Y$ is a matrix}
\]
Need to separate mark and text:
\begin{align}
  X^2 &= Y\footnotemark\\
  Y^2 &= Z
\end{align}\footnotetext{$Y$ is a matrix}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it can happen that the `\footnotetext{...}` ends up on the next page.
I don't know a simple means to prevents that, except to move it *before* the math environment when it happens.