# Footnote in math mode: how to use symbols instead of numbers?

Tags: math-mode, footnotes

In [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode) and [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/can-i-make-footnote-inside-an-equation) post, it is explained how to put a footnote in math mode. The problem is that the number of `footnotemark` might be confused with exponents and viceversa: how can I use a symbol (say `§`, for example) instead?

**Note** I wish to use ***symbols only in math mode*** not in the rest of the text.

Comment: It's very simple: *never* footnote formulas. `;-)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't footnote math. Never. However, if you don't want to listen to this advice, here's a way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[papersize={8cm,6cm}]{geometry} % just to save space
\usepackage{bigfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{math}[fnsymbol]
\MakeSortedPerPage{footnotemath}

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footnote{Some text in the footnote}
\[
a^n+b^n\ne c^n\,\footnotemarkmath
\]\footnotetextmath{I found a very smart proof of
this, but the footnote space doesn't contain it.}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I see that you don't have @Christian Hupfer problem with numeration

Comment: @mattiav27: I see that you have a problem with giving proper feedback ;-)

Comment: @egreg If I choose to heed the advice not to footnote math what could be alternative solutions?

Comment: @HennadiiMadan You can footnote the preceding or the following text. The problem with footnote marks in formulas is that they make them ambiguous.