# Skipped footnote numbers in math mode

Tags: footnotes

I want to call [footnotes in](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode) [(self-explanatory) equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/can-i-make-footnote-inside-an-equation), so I use `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext`, but the footnote numbering is going wrong. Numbers skip from 1 to 3 (when I'd want a 2), and when I try to `addtocounter footnote -1`, it doesn't skip anymore, and doesn't increment at all.

Why is that so, and how to get consecutive numbers ?

MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$1^{st}$ footnote call\footnote{some footnote}.
\[a \xrightarrow{2^{nd}\footnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 2}

\[a \xrightarrow{3^{rd}\footnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 3}

\[a \xrightarrow{4^{th}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\footnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ following the pattern, I'd expect this to be 7 without fix, 6 once fixed. But 5??}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do it. Superscripts in math have mathematical meaning and you are confusing the reader with such footnote marks. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155481/2388.

Beside this: Quite a number of math expressions are processed more than once and so change counters. In your case the problem is the arrow, so you should reset the footnote counter before it.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$1^{st}$ footnote call\footnote{some footnote}.
\[a \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}\xrightarrow{2^{nd}\footnotemark} \]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not *really* math-mode, it really is text over the arrow. I did read, and link to, the same answer as you mention. That works, and I maybe I'll look further into "processed several times", I understand that the counter update had been counted twice, that makes sense now ; many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Be kind to your readers and *don't* inflict them footnotes in math mode.

Just to show it's possible, here it is.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\def\ext@arrow#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{%
  \mathrel{\mathop{%
    \let\mathfootnotemark\fake@footnotemark
    \setbox\z@\hbox{#5\displaystyle}%
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{\m@th
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern#3mu{#6}\mkern#4mu$}%
      \hbox{$\scriptstyle\mkern#3mu{#7}\mkern#4mu$}%
      \copy\z@
    }%
    \hbox to\wd\tw@{\unhbox\z@}}%
  \limits
    \@ifnotempty{#7}{^{\if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
                       #7\if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi}}%
    \@ifnotempty{#6}{_{\if0#1\else\mkern#1mu\fi
                       #6\if0#2\else\mkern#2mu\fi}}}%
}
\newcommand{\mathfootnotemark}{%
  \ifmeasuring@
    \fake@footnotemark
  \else
    \footnotemark
  \fi
}
\newcommand{\fake@footnotemark}{%
  \textsuperscript{\the\numexpr\value{footnote}+1\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$1^{st}$ footnote call\footnote{some footnote}.
\[a \xrightarrow{2^{nd}\mathfootnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 2}%
text
\[a \xrightarrow{3^{rd}\mathfootnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 3}%
text
\[a \xrightarrow{4^{th}\mathfootnotemark} a\]
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 4}%
text
\begin{align}
a & \xrightarrow{5^{th}\mathfootnotemark} a \\
b & \xrightarrow{xxxx} b
\end{align}
\footnotetext{$\leftarrow$ this should be footnote 5}%
text
\end{document}
```