# Footnotes inside a system of numbered equations

Tags: equations, footnotes, empheq

Is it possible to insert footnotes inside a system of numbered equations?

I tried to do it with the following code, but the footnote is not shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\frac{d\boldsymbol{q}}{dt} &= \boldsymbol{A} \, \boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{B} \, \boldsymbol{u} \quad \textnormal{EQUAZIONE di STATO} \\
\boldsymbol{y} &= \boldsymbol{C} \, \boldsymbol{q} \quad \textnormal{TRASFORMAZIONE di USCITA\footnote{Notare che la matrice $\boldsymbol{D}$ è nulla il che significa che il sistema è strettamente proprio, ossia che, dato un ingresso, l'uscita corrispondente non si manifesta istantaneamente, ma occorre un certo tempo per potersi rivelare.}}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please see the following link for your question: [LINK](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/can-i-make-footnote-inside-an-equation)

Comment: @Kuttens very great! I used \footnotemark and \footnotetext.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split up `\footnote` into `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext{...}`.
Use `\footnotemark` in the equation where it should appear and `\footnotetext{...}` outside of the `empheq` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

hello world\footnote{a test before}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\frac{d\boldsymbol{q}}{dt} &= \boldsymbol{A} \, \boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{B} \, \boldsymbol{u} \quad \textnormal{EQUAZIONE di STATO} \\
\boldsymbol{y} &= \boldsymbol{C} \, \boldsymbol{q} \quad \textnormal{TRASFORMAZIONE di USCITA\footnotemark}
\end{empheq}
\footnotetext{Notare che la matrice $\boldsymbol{D}$ è nulla il che significa che il sistema è strettamente proprio, ossia che, dato un ingresso, l'uscita corrispondente non si manifesta istantaneamente, ma occorre un certo tempo per potersi rivelare.}

goodbye world\footnote{a test afterwards}

\end{document}
```

---

If you use several `\footnotemark`s before the corresponding `\footnotetext` you must explicitly specify with an optional argument to which mark the text refers to.

The counter counting the footnotes is called `footnote`, consequently you can access it's current value with `\thefootnote`.

You can perform the required subtraction using `\numexpr`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts, empheq}

\begin{document}

hello world\footnote{a test before}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{align}
\frac{d\boldsymbol{q}}{dt} &= \boldsymbol{A} \, \boldsymbol{q} + \boldsymbol{B} \, \boldsymbol{u} \quad \textnormal{EQUAZIONE di STATO\footnotemark} \\
\boldsymbol{y} &= \boldsymbol{C} \, \boldsymbol{q} \quad \textnormal{TRASFORMAZIONE di USCITA\footnotemark}
\end{empheq}
\footnotetext[\numexpr\thefootnote-1\relax]{an additional footnote}
\footnotetext{Notare che la matrice $\boldsymbol{D}$ è nulla il che significa che il sistema è strettamente proprio, ossia che, dato un ingresso, l'uscita corrispondente non si manifesta istantaneamente, ma occorre un certo tempo per potersi rivelare.}

goodbye world\footnote{a test afterwards}

\end{document}
```