# Numbering the equations in LaTeX with minipage and eqnarray

Tags: equations, footnotes, minipage

I have several problems with using eqnarray and minipage at the same time. When I'm using only eqnarray, I have good numbered equations but can't add footnotes to them (with minipage I can add footnotes, but equations not numbered). What should I do, maby switch some packages?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{split}
P_L_S(f)=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\*\Bigg\{\frac{[\sum_{k=1}^N\*(x_k-\bar{x})\cos(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))]^2}{\sum_{k=1}^N\*\cos^2(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))}\\+\frac{[\sum_{k=1}^N\*(x_k-\bar{x})\sin(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))]^2}{\sum_{k=1}^N\*\sin^2(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))}\Bigg\}\footnote[2]{To see more about Matlab Plomb equations and described in Equation 4.1 variables, \newline visit Matlab Plomb Documentation www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html} 
\end{split}
\end{minipage}
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: Regarding your use of `equnarray` which is generally not recommended, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: Regarding footnotes in equations, [Can I make footnote inside an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/155470/134144) might be helpful. Apart from that, your equation will cause an "Double subscript." error message due to the use of `P_L_S(f)`. Probably you wanted to use `P_{LS}(f)` or `P_{L_S}(f)` instead?

Comment: Do you *really* need a footnote to an equation? Isn't it better to set the text below it?

Comment: leandriis, but if I use `equation`, my equation would appear on the next page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments and suggestions:

- I can see no justification or excuse whatsoever for using an `eqnarray` environment here.
- Place the `equation` *inside* the `minipage`.
- Use an `{aligned}[b]` environment to split the material across two rows.
- Place the `\footnote` directive immediately after `\end{aligned}` and before `\end{equation}`.
- Optional: Insert horizontal rules (via `\hrule`) above and below the `minipage` in order to create some visual separation from the surrounding material.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xurl,lipsum}
\urlstyle{same}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] % filler text

\bigskip\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\hrule % <-- insert a horizontal rule (optional)
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}[b]
P_{L_{S(f)}}=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} 
&\Biggl\{ \frac{\bigl[\sum_{k=1}^N (x_k-\bar{x})\cos(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))\bigr]^2}{%
                      \sum_{k=1}^N \cos^2(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))}\\
&\quad   +\frac{\bigl[\sum_{k=1}^N (x_k-\bar{x})\sin(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))\bigr]^2}{%
                      \sum_{k=1}^N\*\sin^2(2\pi{f}(t_k-\tau))}
 \Biggr\}
\end{aligned}\raisebox{1\baselineskip}{\footnote{To see more about Matlab Plomb equations and described in Equation 4.1 variables, visit Matlab Plomb Documentation \url{www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html}.}}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
\hrule\bigskip % <-- another horizontal rule (optional)
\lipsum[2] % more filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now my problem solved.