# footnote (with hyperref) in align environment (or: reference to calculation steps in footnotes)

Tags: hyperref, align, footnotes

In equations, I want to refer footnotes over the equal sign to explain, which rules or calculation steps are used.

This MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

%%% PACKAGES %%%
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%%% FOOTNOTE COMMAND %%%
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

%%% COLORS %%%
\newcommand{\red}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
\newcommand{\green}[1]{\textcolor{green!50!black}{#1}}
\newcommand{\blue}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}}

%%% HYPER SETUP %%%
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor = blue,
}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[3] \\

We compute\footnote{Some footnote!}

\begin{align*}
    [\div{(\vb*{A} \cross \vb*{B})}]_{i} &= \partial_{i} [\vb*{A} \cross \vb*{B}]_{i} = \varepsilon_{ijk} \green{\partial_{i}}(A_{j} B_{k}) \overset{\text{\green{P}\footnote{product rule}} }{=} \varepsilon_{ijk} (B_{k} \green{\partial_{i}} A_{j} + A_{j} \green{\partial_{i}} B_{k}) \\
                                         &= \varepsilon_{ijk} B_{k} \partial_{i} A_{j} + \varepsilon_{ijk} A_{j} \partial_{i} B_{k} \overset{\text{\blue{I}\red{P}}\footnote{index permutation} }{=} \varepsilon_{ijk} B_{\blue{i}} \partial_{\blue{j}} A_{\blue{k}} \red{-} \varepsilon_{ijk} A_{\red{i}} \partial_{\red{j}} B_{k} \\
                                         &= B_{i} [\curl{\vb*{A}}]_{i} - A_{i} [\curl{\vb*{B}}]_{i} \\
                                         &= [\vb*{B} \vdot (\curl{ \vb*{A}} ) - \vb*{A} \vdot (\curl{ \vb*{B}})]_{i}. 
\end{align*}



\end{document}
```

gives the following:
[image]

The goal is, that the `\dagger` symbol next to `\green{P}` and the `\ddagger` symbol next to `\blue{I}\red{P}` should disappear.
The `\green{P}` and `\blue{I}\red{P}` should be the footnotemarks themself and refer to the footnotetexts `product rule` and `index permutation`.

The solution should look like this:
[image]

If it is not possible or at least very complicated with a small amount of code to set `\green{P}` and `\blue{I}\red{P}` as footnotemarks, I am also fine with an `asterisk`-symbol (which then should be black).

I tried solutions mentioned in the posts [Can I make footnote inside an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155470/can-i-make-footnote-inside-an-equation) and [Footnote in align environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/footnote-in-align-environment), which unfortunately not solve my problem (since the seperation of a `\foonote` into `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` seems to break the reference used by the `hyperref`-package inside an `align`-environment).

I appreciate any comments and attempts to a possible solution!