# problem with footnote in tcolorbox (math mode)

Tags: math-mode, footnotes, tcolorbox

I have problem with footnote in [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox), footnote mark on math mode is numbering with arabic while in the footnote area is numbering with alphabet.

This is an example to show you what I mean,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
        \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from main box}

    \begin{align*}
        f(x) = mx + b\footnotemark
    \end{align*}
    \footnotetext{test footnote equation from main box}
    \tcblower
        \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from lower box}

        \begin{align*}
            f(x) = mx + b\text{\footnotemark}
        \end{align*}
        \footnotetext{test footnote equation from lower box}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from main page}

    \begin{align*}
        f(x) = mx + b\footnotemark
    \end{align*}
    \footnotetext{test footnote equation from main page}
\end{document}
```

Also, the footnote won't increased automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Kopka and Daly, A Guide to LaTeX, p. 96--97, the \footnote command is not allowed in math mode. If you really want to use it you can use code from [Footnote in align enviroment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/footnote-in-align-enviroment):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \iffirstchoice@
      \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
        \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from main box}

    \begin{align*}
        f(x) = mx + b\AlignFootnote{test footnote equation from main box}
    \end{align*}
    \tcblower
        \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from lower box}

        \begin{align*}
            f(x) = mx + b\AlignFootnote{test footnote equation from lower box}
        \end{align*}
    \end{tcolorbox}

    \lipsum[1]\footnote{Footnote from main page}

    \begin{align*}
        f(x) = mx + b\footnotemark
    \end{align*}
    \footnotetext{test footnote equation from main page}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really work perfectly even when implemented with `\hyperref`. `\footnotemark` actually failed when using `\hyperref` (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21813/footnote-in-math-mode#comment41929_21817)