# Foonotes in multlined equations inside minipages

Tags: footnotes, amsmath, minipage, mathtools

I am having the exact same problem as describe [in this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82782/footnote-in-align-enviroment).  Unfortunately, however, the solutions listed there do not seem to work for the `multlined` environment as well.

A MWE is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter                       % This code works as
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%    % a fix for multline
  \ifmeasuring@                     % environments, but
  \else                             % not for multlined
    \iffirstchoice@                 % environments
      \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
x=\AlignFootnote{This is a footnote.}0.
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
x=\AlignFootnote{This is a footnote.}0.
\end{multline}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This outputs the following.
[image: Output]

It seems as if this fix was only made to work for environments coming from `amsmath`, but not `mathtools`.  Unfortunately, my TeXnichal skills are nowhere near good enough for me to be able to extrapolate this to a solution that also works for `mathtools`.  Perhaps someone else more competent can see how to modify the fix (or just create a new one)?

Comment: The reason is that `multlined` uses a very different model from the other alignment environments. For instance it also conflicts with `substack`, so it's not really a surprise it fails with other specific `amsmath` constructs.

Comment: I think we can solve this by making sure that the `multlined` measuring is actually setting `\measuring@true`

Comment: BTW: what is wrong with `multiline` used inside a minipage

Comment: @daleif -- 
 
the peculiar formatting of the `multline` expression is because `multline` should never be used with only one line. this wasn't intended, and probably never tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad behavior has been fixed in the current version of `mathtools` (2015/11/12 v1.18).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\makeatletter                       % This code works as
\newcommand{\AlignFootnote}[1]{%    % a fix for multline
  \ifmeasuring@                     % environments, but
  \else                             % not for multlined
    \iffirstchoice@                 % environments
      \footnote{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
x=\AlignFootnote{This is a footnote.}0.
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
x=\AlignFootnote{This is a footnote.}0.
\end{multline}
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\begin{equation}
\begin{multlined}
x=0.
\end{multlined}
\end{equation}
\begin{multline}
x=0.
\end{multline}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The second minipage has been added for checking the output without footnotes.

[image]