# Why is this footnote displayed four times?

Tags: beamer, equations, footnotes

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
 $A$ is a clopen set iff
    \begin{equation*}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\&\neg A \in \mathcal{A}\text{\footnote{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}}
    \end{equation*}         
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

However, the slide looks like this:

[image]

Please, help :(

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82820/2388

Comment: Off topic, but it's probably better to avoid putting a footnote inside the equation in the first place. Here it looks like you're talking about an element of a set called A^1, and I'm sure that would confuse me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way, it appears only once:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
            $A$ is a clopen set iff
            \begin{equation*}
                A \in \mathcal{A}\&\neg A \in \mathcal{A}\footnote{\text{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}}
            \end{equation*}         
        \end{definition}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason for using `\text`, neither around `\footnote` nor inside it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
 $A$ is a clopen set iff
    \begin{equation*}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\mathrel{\&}\neg A \in \mathcal{A}
        \footnote{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}
    \end{equation*}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note `\mathrel{\&}` in order to get better spacing.

But why a footnote?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
 $A$ is a clopen set iff
    \begin{equation*}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\mathrel{\&}\neg A \in \mathcal{A}
        \footnote{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}
    \end{equation*}
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
 $A$ is a clopen set iff
    \begin{equation*}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\mathrel{\&}\neg A \in \mathcal{A}
    \end{equation*}
Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}[Clopen Set]
 $A$ is a clopen set iff
    \begin{equation}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\&\neg A \in \mathcal{A}\tag*{\footnote{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}}
    \end{equation}
 or
    \begin{equation}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\&\neg A \in \mathcal{A}\tag*{Equivalently, $A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}$}
    \end{equation} 
 or
    \begin{align*}
        A \in \mathcal{A}\&\neg A \in \mathcal{A} && \text{Equivalently, } A \in\mathcal{A} \cap \neg \mathcal{A}
    \end{align*} 
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]